# Is there a regular expression for this?

Tags: c#, xml, regex

I have a problem finding a regular expression. I have some text, maybe divided by some xml. For example:

```
<root>
  <text>Thi</text>
  <text>s is ju</text>
  <text><bold>s</bold></text>
  <text>t a tes</text>
  <text><italic>t</italic></text>
</root>
```

I want to search for the word "just" in the xml and need the result

```
ju</text>
<text><bold>s</bold></text>
<text>t
```

Is there any posibility to get this result with a regular expression?

By the way: I already have the regular expression to get the plain text from the xml, it is (in C#-Syntax):

```
string plaintext = new Regex(@"\<[^\<]*\>").Replace(xmlstring, string.Empty);
```

This one finds every "<" to ">" with everything (*) in between but not another "<" and replaces it with string.Empty. So i get the plain text and could search for my "just", but the result would just be "just", not with the xml in between...

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Don't use regular expressions for this; they are not appropriate for parsing XML. Use a real XML parser instead, that's what they're for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better don't use regexp over xml. Just don't.

According to your task, after each character of string you are looking for, you can expect any xml tags. So basically you need to insert 'maybetag' regex part after each letter - something like this:

```
j(\<[^\<]*?\>\s*)*u(\<[^\<]*?\>\s*)*s(\<[^\<]*?\>\s*)*t(\<[^\<]*?\>\s*)*
```

Working sample http://www.rexfiddle.net/WdkpliZ

Comment: Will match even if there is space before `s` or `t` - `ju st` or `jus t`.

Comment: Sure, it's idea and not fully working sample of course. It won't work in many case, like if XML has CDATA items etc - and again, regexp is not a tool to parse XML.

Comment: Yes, you're right about regex and xml, but as quick solution for searched text highlighting or preserving text formatting of extracted block it may be feasible (I guess author wants to implement these tasks).

Answer (score 1):

If you have XML in single line (with no whitespaces), you can create your regex by splitting letters in `just` by `(?:<[^>]*>)*` regex parts. Example:

```
j(?:<[^>]*>)*u(?:<[^>]*>)*s(?:<[^>]*>)*t
```

If you still need to process multiline xml, you can split letters by `(?! )(?:<[^>]*>\s*)*(?<! )` regex. It would allow whitespaces between XML tags, but wouldn't allow space before or after letter.

```
j(?! )(?:<[^>]*>\s*)*(?<! )u(?! )(?:<[^>]*>\s*)*(?<! )s(?! )(?:<[^>]*>\s*)*(?<! )t
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/j(<[^>]+>)*u(<[^>]+>)*s(<[^>]+>)*t/
```